# SWIFT - Get values from userInfo to populate a fields of a Push Notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I need to populate the fields of a push notification (`.title` and `.body`) using the userInfo. I tried everything but I can only enter the "date" code block. How can I do?
Thank you.

This is my output when i send a push notification from my console php:
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxYBb.png)

My code in `AppDelegate` :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //OTHER CODE
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background  || state == .inactive {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let data = userInfo["data"] as! NSString //If i try to cast to NSDictionary, it will give me nil. Instead in this way i can see my output.
        print("DATA: \n\(data)\n")
        let title = ?? HELP
        let message = ?? ME!
        content.title = "\(title)"
        content.body = "\(message)"
        content.sound = .default
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "t", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    } else if state == .active {
        self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: "Okkey", message: "Test",imageName: "", buttonTitle: "OK", window: self.window!)
    }
```

Comment: Please share your printed data in the console so we can help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root : Codable {
  let title:String
  let message:String
}

if let str = userInfo["data"] as? String {
   let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:str.data(using:.utf8)!)
   print(res?.title)
   print(res?.message)
}
```

Comment: DUDE. Thanks u so much. 
I was about to go crazy

Answer (score 0):

In your userInfo you ahve already a Dictionary!
You can have your title and message ike this

```
let title = userInfo["title"]
let message = userInfo["message"]
```

Comment: op means what inside the data , make sure to cast the type also

Comment: Yeah it's already in the userInfo :) If you try to print or debug userInfo you can see it